# How can i make toggle-able html buttons POST to php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make an html/php email form that includes multiple text fields, 4 toggle-able buttons, and a submit button. I have been successful in getting the buttons to change states when clicked, but I can't figure out how to check whether the button has actually been pressed in PHP.

Here is my html code of all of my buttons. They are wrapped in a form that contains the submit button and other text fields. I also tried changing the button tags to input tags.

```
<section>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="app" value="Web App" type="button">Web App</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="brand" value="Branding" type="button">Branding</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="design" value="Web Design" type="button">Web Design</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="other" value="Other" type="button">Other</button>
</section>
```

My php for just the buttons:

```
if(isset($_POST['app'])) {
    $service .= $_POST['app'];
}
if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
    $service .= ", " . $_POST['brand'];
}
if(isset($_POST['design'])) {
    $service .= ", " . $_POST['design'];
}
if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
    $service .= ", " . $_POST['other'];
}
```

I tried a vardump($_POST); but they are apparently not even added to the $_POST.
Any idea what I can try to get them to actually submit data to the $_POST? I was thinking about doing something like:

```
if(class_exists('active-button')) {
    $service .= //Set data here somehow.
}
```

but I'm not quite sure how I would do that since there are four different buttons and any combination of them can be selected.

Also, shouldn't affect anything I don't think, but here is my jquery for changing the buttons:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    //Add/remove active-button and service-button. Replaces one with the
    //other depending on the current state.
    $(this).toggleClass("active-button").toggleClass("service-button");
});
```

The active-button and service-button classes are simply used in the css the change the style of the button to

Comment: Why dont you use radio buttons for the job?

Comment: Not sure if maybe I'm just misinformed, but I want my buttons styled a certain way and I haven't been able to do that with radio buttons. Here is what they currently look like:
http://puu.sh/pUgU3/05c17e88cc.png
http://puu.sh/pUgUI/6df75bebf2.png

Comment: You can style radio buttons  like what you want but, a javascript based solution is possible too.

Comment: No worries. Figured out how to do it with buttons. See the answer below.

Comment: yes..gr8 it all worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add hidden input and whenever you clicking on button change hidden value and submit hidden field.

HTML

```
<section>
<input class="selected_button" name="selected_button" value="" type="hidden">
    <button class="btn service-button" name="app" value="Web App" type="button">Web App</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="brand" value="Branding" type="button">Branding</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="design" value="Web Design" type="button">Web Design</button>
    <button class="btn service-button" name="other" value="Other" type="button">Other</button>
</section>
```

Jquery

```
//On button click
$(".btn").click(function() {
    //The string to add to the selected-button value
    var toAdd = $(this).attr("value");
    //Add/remove active-button and service-button. Replaces one with the
    //other depending on the current state.
    $(this).toggleClass("active-button").toggleClass("service-button");
    //Checks if the button has already been added in case the user deselects the button
    if($(".selected_button").val().indexOf(toAdd) >= 0) {
        //Removes the comma and text 
        $(".selected_button").val($(".selected_button").val().replace((', ' + toAdd), ''));
    //If the button is being added for the first time
    } else {
        //Adds the comma and text
        $(".selected_button").val($(".selected_button").val() + ", " + toAdd);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$selected = $_POST['selected_button'];
if(isset($_POST['selected_button'])) {
    $service .= $selected;
}
?>
```

Hope it will help

or 
Note:

```
you use radio buttons by using css style you can display like button
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. There were a couple changes I made to make it remove the attributed value if the button is clicked again. I will edit your post momentarily for others with the same issue as me.